# How to find Vx?

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, resistors

[image]

I tried doing this, the answer is 0.87V. but however i did it, i got 1.43V for the final answer. 
Here is the idea of my solution, did i get the concept wrong?
I can only use Delta-Wye, KCL, KVL, CDR, VDR and Source Transformation.

[image: ans]

Comment: Welcome to EESE, since this is a homework problem, please add what you have done so far, since **people can help you with details and hints** but will not do your homework for you.

Comment: One thing I can tell you is that, you will use Thévenin/Norton transformations and it also helps to know what is a balanced Wheatstone bridge.

Comment: @jDAQ I am new here, thank you for the info! I added my solution for further discussion

Comment: That last step where you get the voltage supply with V=5.37 seems weird, what did you do?

Comment: @jDAQ using source transformation, where first, i added 2A + 0.5A = 2.5A. then i added resistor that is parallel 4 and 4.67 = 2.15 ohm. since the resistor and current source are parallel, i change it to voltage to simplify the circuit.

Comment: Those two resistors are not in parallel, they are not connected to the same two nodes

Comment: @ans I agree with your own answer, just looking over things quickly. I see 10 V in series with 4 ohms and two series chains in parallel. There's no current in the 2 ohm that stretches between the two parallel chains. So it is really simple. And I think you are right.

Comment: @jonk but did i get the concept wrong in my solution? is 4 and 4.67 could not be added rightaway?

Comment: Oui, the answer is correct, 1.428 V. I will post a symbolic solution using the EET. In the final expression, the upper right resistance plays no role.

Comment: Between the 3rd and 4th schematic the step is definitely incorrect, those two resistors (4 and 4.67) are not in parallel. It so happens that it didn't affect much the numeric value of Vx (you got 1.435 and @VerbalKint got 1.428), but I disagree to say that your answer is correct just because the final voltage is close enough. At that step you probably should have just converted the R=4 and the I=2.5 to a Thévenin with V=10 and R = 4, in series with the R=0.67 and the other circuit.

Comment: @jDAQ thank you so much! now i get it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll walk you through the steps you might have taken and you can work out where you went wrong, though the answer is right. First off, you are allowed to call any **one** node in a circuit "ground" or \$0\:\text{V}\$. It's your call which one you use. But it's free. So it is usually a good idea to pick something "convenient" or "useful" for later thinking. In my case, I just picked the bottom node, like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBNlxq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now, by inspection, you can see another convenient step: using a Thevenin to Nortion conversion that will allow you to compute two current sources into one, then allowing you to convert back to the final Thevenin result. While we are at it, we may as well also combine \$R_2\$ and \$R_3\$ as they are in parallel to each other:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fX13LH.png)</sup>

At this point, something else becomes clear. There will be no current in \$R_4\$. You should be able to see this by simply mentally removing \$R_4\$ and noticing that the voltages at the nodes on both sides of \$R_4\$ must be equal to each other. Since the voltages are equal, there cannot be any current as there must be \$0\:\text{V}\$ across \$R_4\$. So \$R_4\$ can take on any value without changing the circuit. (We could short it or leave it open or anything in between.)

Let's short \$R_4\$ and combine the previous \$R_\text{parallel}\$ with \$R_5\$ (as parallel resistors, now) and then add that into \$R_{\text{TH}_1}\$ (which they'd be in series with):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4jK9I.png)</sup>

At this point, you should be able to readily see that \$V_x=\frac12 V_y\$. So let's just combine \$R_6\$ and \$R_7\$, put that in parallel with \$R_8\$ and then solve for \$V_y\$:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7JjdM.png)</sup>

This is just a simple resistor divider calculation: \$V_y=V_\text{TH}\frac{R_y}{R_y+R_\text{TH}}\$. Therefore, \$V_x=\frac12 V_\text{TH}\frac{R_y}{R_y+R_\text{TH}}\$.

Comment: Thank you so much! It is really helpful!

Comment: @ans I'm glad it helped out and it makes me feel good that I was able to write in a way that you could follow (I'm hoping so, anyway.) Thanks for letting me know it helped out! It makes the time very much worth it!

Comment: My basic is quite weak. It really did help a lot. God bless you sir! :)

Comment: @jonk, quick and clean analysis as always : ) Did you notice the upper right resistor plays no role with the actual components values?

Answer (score 0):

Despite the correct answer quickly found by the OP, I was interested to find a symbolic solution to this problem using the extra-element theorem or [EET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extra_element_theorem) introduced by Dr. Middlebrook in the 90s. It is an interesting approach to solve a circuit in which a specific element forbids a simple analysis. According to the theorem, the exercise consists of temporarily removing this extra element (or shorting it) while you calculate the intermediate transfer function in this mode. Then, you determine the resistances \$R_d\$ and \$R_n\$ offered by the connecting terminals of this extra element in two conditions:

1. When the excitation source is turned off, you determine \$R_d\$ in this mode
2. When the excitation source is on again but you determine \$R_n\$ when the response is *nulled*. This is what is called a null double injection or NDI.

As the OP mentioned, the two sources can be merged into a single current source delivering 2.5 A and affected by an output resistance of 4 ohms. The equivalent circuit is thus:

[image]

You first calculate the voltage when \$R_7\$ is set to infinity:

[image]

Then, you turn the excitation off and determine the resistance "seen" from \$R_7\$'s terminals when temporarily removed. You may go through a quick intermediate EET with \$R_1\$ as the extra element to find this value:

[image]

Now, bring the excitation back (the 2.5-A source is turned on) and determine the resistance from \$R_7\$'s terminals when the voltage you want to know is equal to 0 V. This is what is called a *null double injection* or NDI. You place a current generator \$I_T\$ across the connecting terminals of \$R_7\$ and determine the voltage \$V_T\$ across this current source when there is no current flowing across \$R_3\$ and \$R_4\$. It is not overly complex and a few KVL/KCL lines get you there:

[image]

We can now assemble the whole thing to form the symbolic expression of the voltage. It is quite ugly I recognize : )

[image]

The complete Mathcad sheet is here and lets you check the intermediate steps:

[image]

All is tested with SPICE sketches individually simulated:

[image]

And if you develop this expression (what you should not since the paralleled terms are what you need for a *low-entropy* expression), then you realize that resistance \$R_7\$ plays no role - oui, as correctly pointed by jonk! - but more funny is that neither \$R_5\$ does: keep the current circuit values and change \$R_5\$ only, the voltage at the wanted node (across \$R_4\$) does not vary.

[image]

The EET is a good tool for obtaining symbolic answers by keeping parallel and series associations. Splitting the circuit in smaller less-complicated pieces was part of the divide-and-conquer strategy thought by Dr. Middlebrook when he forged the EET. As you can see, SPICE is a precious auxiliary for checking all the steps towards the correct answer. This is the method I have described in the [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1119236371) I published on fast analytical circuits techniques.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time! This is very helpful! I got to understand the circuit better

Comment: The answer for the general case becomes quickly difficult to express without the right tool. However, jonk's answer with his multiple transformations is more adapted to a typical exam question where careful examination reveals the absence of current in the horizontal resistor.